# Regex pattern to match comments, but not URLs

Tags: javascript, regex, string, match

I am trying to create a regex for detecting all the comments in a code.
But I am also getting the hyperlinks because of the inline comment characters sequence `//`, which I don't want; I just need the comment part.

```
var sample = `Hello //this is a test
 http://google.com
 //second
 third
 https://test.com`;
var regex = new RegExp(
  /(\/\*([^*|[\r\n]|(\*+([^*\/]|[\r\n])))*\*+\/)|(\/\/.*)/g
);
console.log(sample.match(regex));
```

The output is `["//this is a test", "//google.com", "//second", "//test.com"]`
The output should be `["//this is a test", "//second"]`

Comment: In your code `http:` is text and `//google.com` is comment, there is nothing wrong. You must change how you comment text. How you know if `proto://some.text.here:1234` is comment or link?

Comment: What should be the desired output?

Comment: Anything with http or https should be skipped . My purpose is to just detect commnets in a code.

Comment: See my answer @s_guha96, it's doing exactly that

Comment: If you have to find comments in a code, then try to find first an appropriate parser or tokenizer for this language. If you don't find it, then build a pattern that takes in account (that matches in a capture group) quoted strings. (I assume that your urls are enclosed inside these strings). As an aside, to match a C multiline comment `\/\*[\s\S]*?\*\/` suffices.

Comment: Could you show a real test string ?

Answer (score 1):

For a quick and dirty way, you could use

```
(?<=^|[^\S])\/\/.+
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/dr6SrY/1).

---

In `JavaScript`, this could be

```js
var sample = `Hello //this is a test
 http://google.com
 //second
 third
 https://test.com`;
var regex = new RegExp(/(?<=^|[^\S])\/\/.+/g);
console.log(sample.match(regex));
```

Answer (score -1):

I added newline and 0 or more tabs before your two main capture groups:

```
/[\r\n][/t]*(\/\*([^*|[\r\n]|(\*+([^*\/]|[\r\n])))*\*\/)|[\r\n][\t]*(\/\/.*)/g
```

This means, the comment has to be at the beginning of a new line, so it wont match a hyperlink in the middle of your code.